# where does IValueConverter.Convert source the CultureInfo parameter from?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, localization, cultureinfo, ivalueconverter

I'm going through some silverlight apps and reviewing date formatting to make sure the presentation is appropriate for the viewer.

with an implementation of [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), where does the culture parameter come from in the `Convert/ConvertBack` functions? it seems to not be `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which I think is what I want.

Comment: It's interesting that date.ToString("g") inside of a converter will use the CurrentCulture, not CurrentUICulture.

Comment: @Kevin: That's because you're not using the culture - use the passed in culture inside the converter, unless you want it to differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is intended for your user interfaces, WPF uses [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx), not CurrentCulture.

Comment: so it's meant for menus or buttons or whatever, and not date or money formatting?

Comment: Is CurrentUICulture used for resource files that would provide a language translation? Why is it used in the IValueConveter as the default?